# Language equivalence - manipulation of languages with Star operator

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Why is this always true  $(A^{*} \cap B^{*})^{*} = (A \cap B)^{*}$ ?

$A^{*} = \{  x_{1}x_{2}...x_{k}| k \ge 0$ and each $x_{i} \in A\}$, and similarly for B.

Assuming A and B are any languages i.e. sets of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing something, but the result doesn't seem to be true.

Let $A = \{aa\}$, $B = \{aaa\}$. Then $A \cap B = \emptyset$. However, $A^* \cap B^* = \{ aaaaaa \}^*$ (and hence $(A^* \cap B^*)^* = \{ aaaaaa \}^*$).

Comment: Of course, the result can be salvaged by being more precise about what $aaaaaa$ is, e.g. (assuming $)($ are not in the language) by writing $(aa)(aa)(aa)$ or $(aaa)(aaa)$. That's tedious, but OP ought to become aware of such things.